# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in mpv

Tags: mpv-media-player

I am using `mpv` media player to play my videos and audios.
But I am no longer able to play videos through mpv.
When I run `mpv test.mp4`. Output is given below :

```
abhishek@kamal:~/Videos$ mpv test.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1280x720 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac 2ch 44100Hz)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

#### Edit 1:

When I use `gdb` as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67062):

[image]

Comment: Does this also happen when You start it with `--no-config` option?

Comment: If I use `mpv --no-config test.mp4`. Amazing, video is now playable. But how can I play videos with mouse click.

Comment: This could indicate a problem with your config file. If you don't have a *local* config file in `$HOME/.config/mpv`  you *should* have a system config file in `/etc/mpv/mpv.conf`? If so try `sudo mv /etc/mpv/mpv.conf /etc/mpv/mpv.conf_bak` and then restart mpv...